# Memory allocation for a char ** pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I have to maintain an array of strings, which each string will contain the IP address of a neighbor. For some reason i need to maintain them as strings.

```
 typedef struct _neighbors
 {
      int num_neigbors;
      char **neighbor_address;
 } neighbors;
```

Assume i have two neighbors to add.

I view `char ** neighbor_address` as an array of `char *` pointers.

I understand that i need to `malloc` memory for `neighbor_address[0]` and `neighbor_address[1]` to store their IP addresses. Since the IP address is of form "x.y.z.w" i will be doing a `malloc` of `7*sizeof (char)`.

My doubt is how much memory should i allocate for the base `char **neighbor_address`. Should it be 4 bytes so that it can store the IP address of the base pointer of `neighbor_address[0]`?

I say this because i get a `SIGSEGV` (Segmentation fault) if i don't do a `malloc` as follows:

```
neighbor_address = malloc (1, sizeof (char *));
```

Anything that i am missing?

Comment: 7 chars (eg 6 + 1 for the `\0`) is too less for an ip address, if you want to save it as an string.

Comment: @mch: it is if it's 'of form "x.y.z.w"' (this needs **7** chars, plus a zero). But this only allows 1 digit for each of the components, which is an unrealistic scenario.

Comment: @Jongware: Unless you convert each part into a single byte (so it is not human-readable).

Comment: @Abrixas2: I was waiting for someone to say this! No, that would make the entire question obsolete (using pointers and `malloc` for a variable string length). The storage "form", as asked, is a *string* format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do `malloc` like this-

```
neighbor_address = malloc (1, sizeof (char *));
```

you are not following the syntax of `malloc` here. It is the syntax of `calloc`. If you are using `calloc` you can use this method-

```
neighbor_address = calloc (n, sizeof (char *));
```

If you want to use `malloc` Try the following changes-

```
neighbor_address = (char **)malloc (n * sizeof (char *));
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
neighbor_address[i] = (char *)malloc (8 * sizeof (char));
```

But You are using structure here. So you need to use arrow operator to allocate memory for `char **neighbor_address;` because it is a pointer type. Try this-

```
neighbors -> neighbor_address = (char **)malloc (n * sizeof (char *)); // n -> no of ip addresses
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
neighbors -> neighbor_address[i] = (char *)malloc (8 * sizeof (char));
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think you didn't understand the max length of an IP Address.
It could be 3 digits between every dot so it can be `255.255.255.255` at maximum.

So the code to dynamically allocate memory for it would be so:

```
#define MAX_IP strlen("255.255.255.255")
int i;
neighbors my_neighbors;
my_neighbors.num_neighbors = ?; //Some value that is the num of IP Addresses needed to be stored.
my_neighbors.neighbor_address = malloc(sizeof(char*)*my_neighbors.num_neighbors); //allocate a char* (that is about to be a string) for each neighbor.
for(i = 0 ; i < my_neighbors.num_neighbors ; i++)
{
    my_neighbors.neighbor_address[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(MAX_IP+1)); //Allocating enough room in each IP string for 255.255.255.255 + '\0' (null).
}
//Doing some stuff.
//Freeing memory:
for(i = 0 ; i < my_neighbors.num_neighbors ; i++)
{
   free(my_neighbors.neighbor_address[i]);
}
free(my_neighbors.neighbor_address);
```

And that's it.
Hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate the memory like this.

```
neighbor_address = (char**)malloc(num_neighbors * sizeof(char*));
for(i=0; i<num_neighbors; ++i) {
    neighbor_address[i] = (char*)malloc(len_of_address);
}
```

Make sure that 'len_of_address' is large enough to store all characters (including the terminating '\0' character if you plan to store \0-terminated strings).
Be aware of the fact that you need more space than 1 character per fragment of the ip address if it is a number larger than 9.

So to store 196.168.0.3 you would need at least 12 characters.

Answer (score 0):

First, two things: `sizeof(char)` is 1, regardless of the implementation. And I think you misunderstood malloc prototype. It takes the number of bytes you want to allocate, and it returns the allocated pointer.

If you want to store `x` IPs, then you'll have to do:

```
neighbor_address = malloc(x * sizeof(char*));
```

And then if you want to store 7 chars in each string, you'll have to do:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    neighbor_adress[i] = malloc(7 + 1); // 7 chars plus '\0' character
```

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate memory for an array of `num_neighbors` char pointers. But most of all, remember to `# include <stdlib.h>` : you called `malloc` with wrong parameters, and that's probably what caused the segfault before a wrong size.

The least error-prone pattern for using `malloc` is this one :

```
neighbor_address = malloc(num_neighbors * sizeof *neighbor_address);
```

Just put the same variable as left operand of `=` and operand of `sizeof`, and adjust the number of elements.